# Augmented Reality Development , from where to start ?

Tags: gps, geolocation, augmented-reality

I want to do my final year project on augmented reality geo-localization, 
Please tell me, from where to start ?
what technology to learn ? 
what are recruitments to development this kind of application ?﻿

Answer (score 2):

If you want to perform Geo-Localisation and use GPS, I wouldn't recommend using Unity. It's arbitrary coordinate system can be a bit confusing and difficult to make an app using GPS that's reliable enough.

For Augmented Reality, you can't use anything like Oculus Rift or Google Cardboard, because those are Virtual Reality headsets and have no way of allowing the user to see the real world. Augmented Reality peripherals are things like Microsoft Hololens or Google Glass, neither of which are commercially available but there are cheap knock offs that are. AR can also of course be used on any mobile device, since they all have a camera built-in and chips powerful enough to process all the tracking data.

As for making an actual app, the best thing you can do is have a go. Analyse your market, see where the gaps are. If you want to make an app for a specific OS that isn't cross-platform, I would recommend learning some Objbective-C (for iOS) or Java (for Android), if you don't know any already.

For cross-platform, I would say something like Xamarin would be useful for making an app on both the major OSes, it was recently made free by Microsoft and you can essentially make one app in C# that works across all devices.

For the Augmented Reality itself, there are frameworks out there that can be used for your purposes. Things like Kudan, Vuforia, Wikitude, etc. Some of them offer free versions of their software. You can use these to deal with all the tracking and projection side of things so you don't have to go about creating your own AR engine.

The best thing to do is probably to sit down for a few minutes, or hours, and think about what you're going to do. Figure out what you want the end result to look like, then work backwards and think about the best way to achieve that goal. Eventually you will arrive at the language and engine you want to use to make your life as easy as possible and then you can get started learning from tutorials online and getting your app out into the world.

Answer (score 1):

you can check my tutorial about geo-based augmented reality solution on Android: https://www.netguru.co/blog/augmented-reality-mobile-android
I have presented there the basics and how to start with simple implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Well a good starting point would be to ask yourself few questions:

- What type of devices, you plan to work on(oculus rift, google cardboard, Microsoft Hololens, web etc)?
- Augmented Reality is achievable in both Web-Context and Application-context. Which route do you want to go for?

Depending on these questions, if you choose to do a normal application based on a device, then depending on the device(Oculus Rift, Google Cardboard, Microsoft Hololens), you would need to grab their specific developer kits and learn how to develop apps using the documentation. For Oculus rift and Microsoft Hololens, you would need the respective Headsets inorder to make an app in that, but If it comes to google cardboard, all you need is you mobile phone with a good processing power.

There is another way to work on augmented reality applications, that is by doing a Web Application using some amazing javascript libraries like Awe.js, Three.js and JSARToolkit.

You can google about them and find out more.

Comment: Thank you sir, for your answer, 
after hours of searching online i got an android application similar to my idea. 
It' s named : "Discoberry "
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.creatorsstudio.geodisplay&hl=en 
,
I want to develop exact same application , now tell me how can I develop ? 
steps ? 
things to learn ?

Comment: The question that you are asking is too broad, I can give a direction to look at. Start with google cardboard applications....

Answer (score 0):

One of the more accessible ways to learn Augmented reality is Project Tango. 
Devices are around $500 last I checked and you can use a free version of Unity + Project Tango's free plugin:
https://developers.google.com/project-tango/

Which ever hardware you pick I'd recommend checking out Unity3D as it seems to be the platform of choice for AR/VR at the moment. There are other options... this just provides the most flexibility based on all of the platforms it supports.

Side note: I have no affiliation with Project Tango and am in fact working on another platform... but it isn't as accessible at the moment.

Comment: Project Tango is a very sophisticated framework and their SDK is quite complicated. I wouldn't suggest to learn it for final year project because it could simply take too much time. Although if you think about working professionally with AR in future Tango is a must.